# WPF Printdocument

Tags: wpf, printdocument

Got this code below, how can I send an excel file to the printer?

Edit: I want to send an existing file (excel) to my "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer and then have it save it as a new file (pdf).

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
            {
                PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                {

                    PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF", 

                    PrintToFile = true,

                    PrintFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\pdf\\", "filename.pdf"), 
                }
            };


            doc.Print();
```

Comment: Hi! it compiles without errors. Yes the whole point is to save my excel file as pdf. Right now im only getting a blank pdf file.

Comment: Important info to include. I'd suggest you [edit] to clarify your question. What you want to do, what you tried, what happened and why that didn't work for you are the four parts of a good question, and good questions get correct answers quicker. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in this area, but the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 suggest that it raises an event (which you aren't handling) and it's in the event that you give it what it needs to print your page.

Comment: done! okay, I'll check that link. thanks anyway!